# VBA code selects the first 3 columns INSTEAD of the last 3 columns

Tags: vba, range

I am working on a code that is supposed to get the values from columns that correspond to the last three rows of a table I created. It needs to be under this form because the numbers will be random.

I have a table in the first excel sheet with different values. I calculate how many rows and columns there are.

Then I get the last three values from the second sheet, belonging to the column Index. I will use these indexes in order to construct a code that will obtain these indexes and indentify the columns they correspond to in the first excel sheet. THen, I want it to extract these values for me.

The problem is it gets the three FIRST values not last

How can I fix this?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ThreeBest()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, N As Integer
Dim Valeurs As Integer

Dim nb_Cells As Integer
Dim nb_Actions As Integer


nb_Cells = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1
nb_Actions = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
N = 3 'We want to choose the three last ones

ReDim ValeursAction(nb_Cells) As Variant

For i = 1 To N
        Valeurs = Worksheets("Performance").Cells(nb_Actions + 7 - (i - 1), 9).Value
        'I place the value from the column corresponding to Valeurs in Performance
        For j = 1 To nb_Cells
            ValeursAction(j) = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(j + 1, Valeurs + 1)

        With Sheets("Performance")
                       .Cells(5 + j, 5 - i) = ValeursAction(j)
        End With
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `nb_Actions` is a column number, but in the first line of your loop you're using it as the row index on the "Performance" sheet - did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misunderstood your request, I think that you need to use xlToRight and xlDown to find the last columns and rows respectively.
Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ThreeBest()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, N As Integer
Dim Valeurs As Integer

Dim nb_Cells As Integer
Dim nb_Actions As Integer


nb_Cells = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlDown).Row - 1
nb_Actions = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column - 1
N = 3 'We want to choose the three last ones

ReDim ValeursAction(nb_Cells) As Variant

For i = 1 To N
        Valeurs = Worksheets("Performance").Cells(nb_Actions + 7 - (i - 1), 9).Value
        'I place the value from the column corresponding to Valeurs in Performance
        For j = 1 To nb_Cells
            ValeursAction(j) = Worksheets("Actions").Cells(j + 1, Valeurs + 1)

        With Sheets("Performance")
                       .Cells(5 + j, 5 - i) = ValeursAction(j)
        End With
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You get an overflow with what as an error? Can you point out which line is throwing the error?